# Jenkins and Ruby On Rails 4 in Windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, svn, jenkins, continuous-integration

My team has been using Jenkins to perform Continuous Integration on our Java and C# codebases for a while now.

We recently began developing a new application in Ruby on Rails 4. Obviously, I would like this new RoR codebase to follow the Continuous Integration process.

Our Jenkins installation resides on a Windows machine and all of our code is stored in an SVN repo.

***Is it possible to perform Continuous Integration on RoR code in a Windows environment with Jenkins?***

Comment: If the target platform for the RoR application is other than Windows, why not consider using a [Jenkins slave](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Distributed+builds) node to run those CI builds?

Comment: @AntonioPérez I never even considered that!  Looking into it right now.  I will let you know how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the recommendation from Antonio Perez, I was able to come up with a solution.

I ended up creating a Jenkins user on my Linux development box.  Then I used the built-in "Manage Nodes" functionality in my Jenkins Master to add a slave node onto my Linux development box.  Now I am able to perform CI on my RoR codebase.